# ORACLE JOIN TABLES

Tags: sql, oracle

I have

```
T1: USER_ID OSX
       1     Y
       2     Y  

T2: USER_ID ANDROID
       1     Y
       3     Y
```

I want to join the tables as follows but i don't know how

```
T3: USER_ID ANDROID  OSX
       1     Y        Y
       2     null     Y
       3     Y        null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) as user_id,
       t2.android, t1.osx
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `full join`, better handle null values:

```
select coalesce(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) as user_id,
       coalesce(t2.android,'N/A') as android,
       coalesce(t1.osx,'N/A') as osx
from t1
full join t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Comment: *null* is *null*, why should one want a dummy-value 'N/A' on the database-layer?!